# Compare ISO date without time stamp in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, odata, momentjs

I am querying data using `OData`, url looks like `http://myurl.com/api/Customer?$filter=ResDate eq DateTime'2014-03-15T12:01:55.123'`.

I'm getting `date/time` from `jquery.datepicker` instead of the static date and using `moment.js` to convert from `DD-MM-YYYY` to `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss` in order to pass it to web service.

```
function convertDateToISOdate(date){
    var newDate = moment(date,'DD-MM-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
    return newDate;
}
```

Date returns from the function, is `2014-03-15T00:00:00`.

Problem : `2014-03-15T12:01:55.123` is not equal to `2014-03-15T00:00:00`, so there's no record selected.

What I want is , just to compare the date , not include time stamp.

Note : I can not change the format `date/time` at server side(Web service) because it's not belongs to me.

Any idea is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your first call to `moment(date,'DD-M-YYYY')` is stripping the time information from the incoming data.  try using `moment(date)` (no format) instead because momentjs recognizes your incoming date format intrinsically, without having to be told which format to use, and will correctly parse the H:M:S data, too.

[MomentJS date parse information](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

Comment: Using that technique, URL is `http://myurl.com/api/Customer?$filter=ResDate eq DateTime'1389027600000'`. Error :  `400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: I think you misunderstood me.  What is the date format returned from the server (the content of the "date" parameter for your function)?

Comment: The date is returned from the server, is like `2014-07-17T17:30:13.797`. The reason that I have to have that converting function because the value that shown in text box isn't what the server look like (I don't want to show the date as the server's format in the text box, since it is uneasy for customer to understand it).

Comment: I see now what you are saying.  I misinterpreted your problem.  You appear to be at the mercy of the REST API provider, but it seems a bit strange that you must query on the exact date/time to get any records back.  I note that you are using "eq" in your REST query.  Could it be that there might also be something like "gt" and "lt" (less than/greater than) or a "between"?  If that were the case, you could box your user's request using an upper and lower boundary.  I suggest checking the API documentation (if any) to see if this is possible.

Comment: One more thing, where did the value "2014-03-15T12:01:55.123" come from in your example?  I'm still confused about how you are querying the REST API using such a specific date/time.